# MS Graph API - how to retrieve declined events?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

Let's say person B sends a calendar event invite to person A. When we then run the following query for person A, we can see the event in the response with `responseStatus.response="notResponded"`, which is fine:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?startDateTime=2023-01-11T23%3A00%3A01.000Z&endDateTime=2023-01-12T23%3A00%3A00.000Z
```

However, when person A declines the invitation, then the event disappears from the response.

Is there a way to modify the query or use a different endpoint to still have access to the declined events?

I tried to look for the solution in the MS Graph API docs, but couldn't find any hints.

Answer (score 1):

`responseStatus` property doesn't support filtering but as an alternative you can use extended property `PidLidResponseStatus` and filter those events with `PidLidResponseStatus` equals to `respDeclined` int value `4`.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?startDateTime=2023-01-11T23%3A00%3A01.000Z&endDateTime=2023-01-12T23%3A00%3A00.000Z&$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep:ep/id eq 'Integer {00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x8218' and cast(ep/value, Edm.Int32) eq 4)
```

But if declined event is remove from the calendar then it cannot be listed.

Documentation:

[PidLidResponseStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidlidresponsestatus-canonical-property)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help. I just get an empty list of events...

Comment: Though if I go with `cast(ep/value, Edm.Int32) eq 3` then I get accepted events. So the query looks legit, it just seems there's no way to get declined events from MS

Comment: Try to use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?startDateTime=2023-01-11T23%3A00%3A01.000Z&endDateTime=2023-01-12T23%3A00%3A00.000Z&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'Integer {00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x8218') . It will return PidLidResponseStatus extended property and you can check the correct value for declined events.

Comment: Nope, no luck either :/

Comment: @DominikKapusta If decline event is removed from calendar then it cannot be listed.